# Sort a list of double[,] based on first element of array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting

I have a list of 2d arrays. Now I want to **sort my list** **based on** only  **1st element** of my array - not the second element. I wrote the code as following:

```
List<double[,]> lsResultsOfEq = new List<double[,]>();
double[,] resultOfEqConv;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    resultOfEq = a*b*c;

    //add value and index
    resultOfEqConv = new double[1, 2];
    resultOfEqConv[0, 0] = (double)resultOfEq[0, 0];
    resultOfEqConv[0, 1] = i;
    lsResultsOfEq.Add(resultOfEqConv);
}
```

Now when I use the sort function I get the error "Failed to compare two elements in the array" how should I set my sortlist that only do the sorting based on first elemen of array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `OrderBy` method from [linq](/questions/tagged/linq), for sample:

include the namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

and try this:

```
var orderResult = lsResultsOfEq.OrderBy(x => x[0, 0]).ToList();
```

Comment: It doesnt work, it gives following ERROR: 

'double[*,*]' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'double[*,*]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Sorry, I adjust my sample, I mean applying order by in `lsResultsOfEq` which is an `List<double[,]>`, and `List` can apply the order by.

Answer (score 3):

The straight forward way would be using [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) as pointed out by Felipe Oriani.

Just in case you are looking at List.Sort() for in-place sorting. You may try:

```cs
lsResultsOfEq.Sort((x, y) => x[0, 0].CompareTo(y[0, 0]));
```